# What does role db_owner allow

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, security

I have been trying to troubleshoot a login that is not able to view certain tables in a SQL Server 2012 database. In doing so I find I don't quite understand what membership in the `db_owner` role allows. I can understand the other roles such as `db_datareader and db_datawriter` but I remain confused as to what `db_owner` allows.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Please see the [reference on BOL for Database-Level Roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2012/ms189121(v=sql.110)):

> ### db_owner
>
> Members of the db_owner fixed database role can ***perform all configuration and maintenance activities on the database, and can also drop the database***.

The easiest way to see all of the permissions is to use the `sys.fn_my_permissions()` function.  First verify you are a member of `db_owner`:

```
select
    rol.name
from sys.database_principals mem
inner join sys.database_role_members drm
on drm.member_principal_id = mem.principal_id
inner join sys.database_principals rol
on drm.role_principal_id = rol.principal_id
where mem.principal_id = user_id();
```

Now list out all of the effective database permissions:

```
select *
from sys.fn_my_permissions(null, 'database');
```

That should be granular enough for your purposes.  Something to note, `sys.fn_my_permissions()` returns the *effective* permissions, so think of it as an aggregation.

Comment: Would that mean that user who have `db_owner` membership have by default the same permissions as `db_reader` and `db_writer`?

Comment: A member of the `db_owner` fixed database role will have `SELECT`, `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, and `DELETE` permissions on the database.  Amongst many other permissions, but yes, that's correct.