# DB_OWNER permissions for user

Tags: sql-server

I would like to know if `db_owner` can change the recovery model of database.

Using TSQL-   alter database db set recovery simple

Comment: It's easy for you to try and learn rather having people try and educate you. Have you referred books online ?

Comment: @Rak, http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/69135/what-does-role-db-owner-allow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well , its simple from the word itself db_owner:

> Members of the `db_owner` fixed database role can perform all
>   configuration and maintenance activities on the database, and can also
>   drop the database.

So yes , user with db_owner role can change the recovery model.

Also, for complete understanding please read [Database-Level Roles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms189121.aspx)